# Pass value from clicked button to a function PHP (not using JS)

Tags: php, function, variables, onclick

So here is my question.
Can i somehow put this Onclick event that gives Javascript function variable $i from Php without using javascript,as i want to get the number of clicked button. I know it has something to do with button name, but with that button name i only know how to see if button is clicked with isset (i don't know how to pass value if its clicked to function), i would like to do this entirely in php, but i am stuck here as i don't know what to do, any help would be appreciate.

```
 <?PHP   
 $i=0; 
 foreach($test2 as $test)
  {
       $delete ="<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick='submit_btn(" . $i. ")' NAME='delete".$i."'VALUE='delete'>";

    $i++;

  }
 ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function submit_btn(btnClick) // < -- How to do this in PhP
       {        
           alert(btnClick); // echo would go here 
       }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['delete']) && is_array($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo 'Button ' . $_POST['delete'][0] . ' was clicked.';
  }

  $test2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
?>  

<!doctype html>
...
<html>
  <form method="post">
    <?php
    $i=0; 
    foreach($test2 as $test) {
      echo "<button type='submit' name='delete[]' value='button_{$i}'>
              Delete-Button #{$i}
            </button>";
      $i++;
    }
    ?>
  </form>
</html>
```

Here's a working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LQpHvp

Note that (unlike with JavaScript and Ajax techniques) this will always require a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put it in a test.php file to test it)

```
<form method="post"><?php
$i=0; 
$test2 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
foreach($test2 as $test)
{
    echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="'.$i.'" />';

    $i++;

}
?></form>

<p><?php
// get result

if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    echo $_POST['delete'];
}
?></p>
```